# How to redirect http to https with Gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I use Flask as Web Application, to redirect http to https, I added such codes in app.py:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if request.url.startswith('http://'):
        url = request.url.replace('http://', 'https://', 1)
        return redirect(url, code=301)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

and the gunicorn command in supervisor.conf is:

```
command=/home/MyToDo/venv/bin/gunicorn --certfile=/home/MyToDo/SSL/mytodo.vip.cer --keyfile=/home/MyToDo/SSL/mytodo.vip.key -w3 -b0.0.0.0:443 -b0.0.0.0:80 app:app
```

but when I visit the website, I still need to add "https://" in front the url, it didn't redirect automaticly. So how to make gunicorn redirect http to https, does using Nginx is the only way?

Comment: Well nginx is better suited for this. And gunicorn advise it too: "Gunicorn is a WSGI HTTP server. It is best to use Gunicorn behind an HTTP proxy server. We strongly advise you to use nginx." (taken from the official doc)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem running Flask on Google App Engine Flexible environment with gunicorn. Solved by using **werkzeug.contrib.fixers.ProxyFix** of **Werkzeug** version **0.14.1**.

```
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
app = Flask(__name__)

app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues using Google App Engine and have spend too much time on this since all the answers including `werkzeug.contrib.fixers.ProxyFix` and the official docu's custom `HTTPMethodsOverrideMiddleware` or other custom solutions did **not** work for me.

I finally managed to solve this by configuring `gunicorn` using a config which sets:

`secure_scheme_headers = {'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https'}` and 
`forwarded_allow_ips = '*'`

Additionally, for the ones wanting to serve **static** files and who are struggling with unwanted http redirects, adding handlers for each static directory in the *.yaml* configuration and avoiding nested sub-directories solved this issue.

*Flask==2.1.3*
*gunicorn==20.1.0*